# Aspnetboilerplate emailsender providing null for email sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework, to provide an email system that will distribute when requested. I got the email system working within the UserEmailer. However now the email sender is currently providing no email at this moment of time. It was working perviously but instead of going through EmailSenderBase its now going through NullEmailSender. Is there possible reasons why this could happen and where the issue could be stemming from.

Even from the initial injection the emailSender will be equal to NullEmailSender.

It seems like dependency injection isn't working however I can manually code it using an constructor:

```
_emailSender = new SmtpEmailSender(new SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration(SettingManager));
```

rather than using

```
_emailSender =  emailSender
```

Here are a few resources 
http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/master/src/Abp/Net/Mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out, within core Module, there is a line:

```
IocManager.Register<IEmailSender, NullEmailSender>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

Just had to comment it out as it disables email sending in debug mode